# Expand Regex SubGroup Matches in Java

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I have a function that takes a regex and another string and returns a lambda that matches the regex against whatever input. I want the other string to be able to use matching groups from the regex, but I can't find a way to do this in Java.

Minimal example:

```java
public static Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry> process(String regex, String template){
  return input -> {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
    if(!m.find()){
      return null;
    }
    // Want something like:
    // String key = m.expand(template);
    // That *only* expands template and doesn't add anything else.
        
    // **Doesn't work**
    // m.replaceFirst/appendReplacement keep parts of the original input
    String key = m.replaceFirst(template);
        
    return Map.entry(key, input);
  };
}
    
public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
  String text = "https://www.myaddress.com?x=y&w=z&other=other&q=taco&temp=1";
  Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry> func1 = process("myaddress.com.*[?&]q=(\\w+)", "$1");
  Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry> func2 = process("myaddress.com.*[?&]q=(?<query>\\w+)", "query: ${query}");
  System.out.println(func1.apply(text).getKey());
  // Outputs "https://www.taco&temp=1" want "taco"
  System.out.println(func2.apply(text).getKey());
  // Outputs "https://www.query: taco&temp=1" want "query: taco"
}
```

This example only uses a single capture group, but `regex`/`template` could be anything and we should support it generically (e.g. process should handle `$1 $4 ${mygroup}` as a `template` for a compatible `regex`). Forcing the user to match the entire URL is also undesirable.

Golang has an [`Expand` function for this](https://pkg.go.dev/regexp#Regexp.ExpandString), how can I achieve it in Java without reimplementing the parsing of `$` capture group syntax?

The best workaround I currently have is simply to prepend and append `.*` to the regex string when compiling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my question with my workaround as it seems the most elegant solution available.

---

There is currently no method for this in Java; the best workaround is to expand the match to the entire string.

Expanding the match looks a little different depending on which of [Java's three match operations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) you're using:

- [`matches`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches()) - This already matches against the full string; a match will necessarily include all input.
- [`lookingAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt()) - Matches from start of input, append `.*` to your regex to include the full input in your match<sup>1</sup>.
- [`find`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find()) - Matches any substring in the input, append *and* prepend `.*` to your regex to match the full input.

Then you can use the original solution with [`replaceFirst`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String)) and it will work as expected.

Note that since you're expanding the match to the whole input, once you do so, any match operation becomes equivalent to using `matches`.

<sub><sup>1</sup> Equivalently, in this case you can use [`appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement(java.lang.StringBuilder,java.lang.String)) without calling `appendTail` instead of expanding the match.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

> *"... how can I achieve it in Java without reimplementing the parsing of $ capture group syntax? ..."*

The only way to return captured values would be through the *Pattern* and *Matcher* class.
Or, with the appended `.*`, as you mentioned.

> *"... I want the other string to be able to use matching groups from the regex, but I can't find a way to do this in Java. ...*
>
> ```java
> // Outputs "https://www.taco&temp=1" want "taco"
> ```

Implementing the template syntax is not difficult.
The *[Matcher#namedGroups](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#namedGroups())* method returns a *Map* of capture group names and their group numbers.

```java
String string = template;
for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
    string = string.replaceAll("\\$" + i, m.group(i));
for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : m.namedGroups().entrySet())
    string = string.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + e.getKey() + "}", m.group(e.getValue()));
```

Here is the full re-factor.

```java
public static Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> process(String regex, String template){
    return input -> {
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(input);
        if(!m.find()) return null;
        String string = template;
        for (int i = 1; i <= m.groupCount(); i++)
            string = string.replaceAll("\\$" + i, m.group(i));
        for (Map.Entry<String, Integer> e : m.namedGroups().entrySet())
            string = string.replaceAll("\\$\\{" + e.getKey() + "}", m.group(e.getValue()));
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(string, input);
    };
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
    String text = "https://www.myaddress.com?x=y&w=z&other=other&q=taco&temp=1";
    Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> func1 = process("myaddress.com.*[?&]q=(\\w+)", "$1");
    Function<String, AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<String, String>> func2 = process("myaddress.com.*[?&]q=(?<query>\\w+)", "query: ${query}");
    System.out.println(func1.apply(text).getKey());
    // Outputs "https://www.taco&temp=1" want "taco"
    System.out.println(func2.apply(text).getKey());
    // Outputs "https://www.query: taco&temp=1" want "query: taco"
}
```

Output

```
taco
query: taco
```

Comment: Thanks, it does seem like my workaround or reimplementation is the only way. Personally, I strongly prefer the workaround since it is less code and uses Java's implementation which is guaranteed to handle edge cases and support future enhancements. For example, here you don't support escaping (though easily could, the point is more about having to fix unaccounted for bugs later).

Comment: @River, I believe there is a syntax specification for the replacement pattern, although I haven't been able to find it.  In the mean time just provide error handling. The _Matcher#replaceAll_ method uses the _Matcher#appendExpandedReplacement_ method, you could link it in a _JavaDoc_ comment for your class.  Here is the _OpenJDK_ source, _https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/util/regex/Matcher.java#L1055_.

Comment: I haven't seen any spec like that either. This is all more to my point though, with my workaround you just wrap your regex and don't need to worry about a spec, or error handling, or linking the canonical implementation; you get all that for free by using that canonical implementation.